# Angular Routing: White Screen of Death

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, apache2, url-routing

I am building a single page app.

Everything works fine except for one thing, when I try to use Params in my routing it breaks everything and I get a white screen of death. The HTML code is still there in the background, because I can see it via "View Source."

Here is what works:

```
app.config(function($locationProvider, $httpProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    var numLoadings = 0;
    var loadingScreen = $('<div id="loading-screen"><img src="img/exp_interstitial.gif"/></div>')
    .prependTo($('body')).hide();
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
        return {
            'request': function(config){
                numLoadings++;
                loadingScreen.show();
                return config;
            },
            'response': function(response){
                if (!(--numLoadings)){
                    loadingScreen.hide();
                }
                return response;
            }
        };
    });
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'views/select-token.html',
        controller : 'selectToken'
    })
    .when('/purchase-token', {
        templateUrl : 'views/purchase-token.html',
        controller : 'purchaseToken'
    });
});
```

But when I do this, it breaks (white screen of death, console says "Syntax Error, Unexpected 
Token <":

```
app.config(function($locationProvider, $httpProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    var numLoadings = 0;
    var loadingScreen = $('<div id="loading-screen"><img src="img/exp_interstitial.gif"/></div>')
    .prependTo($('body')).hide();
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
        return {
            'request': function(config){
                numLoadings++;
                loadingScreen.show();
                return config;
            },
            'response': function(response){
                if (!(--numLoadings)){
                    loadingScreen.hide();
                }
                return response;
            }
        };
    });
    $routeProvider
    .when('/token/:token', {
        templateUrl : 'views/select-token.html',
        controller : 'selectToken'
    })
    .when('/purchase-token/token/:token', {
        templateUrl : 'views/purchase-token.html',
        controller : 'purchaseToken'
    });
});
```

The code is exactly the same but I added a param `:token`. I have already changed apache2 config by adding: `FallbackResource /index.html`.

I am really lost on what could be causing the white screen of death syntax error since I am doing everything by the book.

On my front end I am using these scripts (which are being loaded at the bottom of the HTML page):

```
<!-- Angular JS -->
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loading-bar.js"></script>
```

Is this the wrong syntax? Am I missing any angular modules? Any help on whats causing this issue would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: could you please share your views html and controllers? Maybe one of them breaks depending on the route. Also try to replace `purchase-token/token/:token` by `/purchase-token/:token`, maybe the routes with the same ending break somehow.

Comment: You no longer have a default route ... are you hitting one of the defined routes?